# MySQL Query Multiple LEFT JOIN with WHERE column NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql

Having trouble finding workable syntax to perform this query

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (307)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

Works fine.

What I'm trying to do is add this

```
WHERE wp_posts.title NOT LIKE '%lug'
```

I've tried many variations.. but they all result in error.

Tried

```
AND WHERE wp_posts.title NOT LIKE '%lug'
```

after the second `WHERE`

I've also tried adding it before the `LEFT JOIN`

Just getting a generic syntax error wherever I try to place it in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition of left joined  table should be  added  to on clause and not in where  otherwise works as inner join

```
  SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
        ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
              and   wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (307)
  WHERE  wp_posts.title NOT LIKE '%lug'
  GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

*you should not use group by if you don'have aggregation function  (use disticnt if yoy neeed) this behavior is deprecated  in sql and in some version is not more allowed*